# Ideas - storing jquery parameters for later use in partial view

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

Ok, let me try to clearly explain what I'm attempting to accomplish here.

Basically, I have a site that is using a liberal dose of jquery to retrieve partialviews into a consolidated 'single view'. So far so good - it all works great and is very performant.

However, I would like to have the ability to 'flag' (using a button) any such set and as a consequence of flagging it, add it to a functional area that I have dubbed 'active-tasks'. What I'd like to do is to be able to then goto that 'active-tasks' panel and see a range of ui tabs that represented the consolidated views that I had added. Clicking on any tab would then re-invoke that consolodated view afresh with the parameters that had been used at the time of flagging it. This would therefore mean that I'd have to store the parameters (?) for creating that consolidated view, rather than the generated html (this part i can do at the moment).

So, any thoughts on how to elegantly store the code required to generate the consolidated view on clicking a tab button - no pressure :)

cheers - jim

Comment: So the "active-tasks" partial view would be a clone of the original partial view and in fact you could have multiple clones?  All on the same web page?

Comment: Rake36 - yes, exactly. so probably not just a straightfwd query and dump case. would need a little thought re id's etc given that the same 'type' of 'active-task' could be included as a tab on the same 'page' (tho obviously not visible at the same time). my thinking is that each new containing div would obviously capture the unique id of the uniqueness of that model and we'd then wrk from that starting point.

well observed tho :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, after a minimal amount of research, it looks like the newly updated .data() jquery method (with the ability to add an object to the payload) may work for the above.

http://api.jquery.com/data/

basically, this allows you to add hash type keyed data to an id element for use later, so in my scenario above i could simply attach the parameters required to invoke the action method that related to my consolidated view on the tab.

I'll let you know how i progress with this...

jim